# How to include a column from table-2 into table-1?

Tags: mysql, sql

Apologies if this is basic, I am new to MySQL. I have SQL table-1 with Id, prod-name, prod-description and table-2 with Id, prod-price. I need to export the data as a CSV file to import into a website and I can't import them separately. Is there a way to export from SQL a CSV file so that I can have table-2's prod-price included with the data from table-1?

Comment: How exactly are the two tables related?

Comment: Does "id" of both table is the same?

Comment: Fubar and KKK - table-1 and table-2 share the same ID. (thanks for your attention to this)

Comment: if i understand right, this is the command you are looking for `mysql --database your_database -e "select query" > /your_path/test.csv;`

Comment: Thanks Sivabalan, but I don't really understand how to use what you're stating there. Can you elaborate please.

Comment: I found this page which explains what I need to do http://www.dummies.com/programming/databases/combine-information-from-multiple-mysql-tables-with-join/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was after.

```
SELECT
    table-a.BasePrice,
    table-b.ClassName,
    table-b.Title,
    table-b.Content
FROM
    table-a,
    table-b
WHERE
    table-a.ID = table-b.ID
```

I was then able to export the results as a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to write the query uses standard, readable, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Commas in the from clause have been obsolete for decades.  So:

```
SELECT a.BasePrice, b.ClassName, b.Title, b.Content
FROM `table-a` a JOIN
     `table-b` b
     ON a.ID = b.ID;
```